# Ionic 2: how to process response from a POST

Tags: angularjs, json, http, ionic-framework

I'm feeling like a stupid.
I want to ask to my APIs with a POST that give me a json.
How can I access to one of the json fields and send to the page that calls this?

I have this provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  data: any;
  result: any;
  http: Http;

  public login(credentials) {

    if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
      return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
    } else {
      return Observable.create(observer => {
        // At this point make a request to your backend to make a real check!
        this.data = {api_token: "asdfg", http_id: credentials.email, http_pass: credentials.password};
        this.http.post('http://mywebsite/api/login', JSON.stringify(this.data), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
        .map(res => res.json())

        let access = (credentials.password === "pass" && credentials.email === "email");
        observer.next(access);
        observer.complete();
      });
    }
  }

  public logout() {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get data from response, this is enough

```
public login(credentials) {
if (credentials.email === null || credentials.password === null) {
  return Observable.throw("Please insert credentials");
} else {
    let data = {api_token: "asdfg", http_id: credentials.email, http_pass: credentials.password};
    return this.http.post('http://mywebsite/api/login', JSON.stringify(data), {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
    .map(res => res.json())
}}
```

In component you can access them as

```
provider.login(cred).subscribe(res => { 
console.log(res) },
err => {
console.log(err)
)
```